# How to run jasmine-node tests with RequireJS

Tags: node.js, requirejs, jasmine-node

How can I properly run jasmine tests using jasmine-node and RequireJS?

I already tried something like this, but doesnt work (CoffeeScript):

```
requirejs = require 'requirejs'
requirejs.config { baseUrl: __dirname + '/../' }

requirejs ['MyClasses', 'FooClass'], (MyClasses, FooClass) ->

  describe "someProp", ->
    it "should be true", ->
      expect(MyClasses.FooClass.someProp).toEqual true
```

**Finished in 0 seconds 0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures**

My goal is to write modular classes using RequireJS, CoffeeScript and classes must be testable with jasmine-node (CI server).

How can I do that please?
Thank you!

EDIT:

I executing tests with command (at directory with tests):

```
jasmine-node ./
```

Comment: How are you executing jasmine? If you put a `console.log 'hello'` inside the `requirejs` block, does it print? Inside the `it`? How about outside the `requirejs` block?

Comment: `Outside` of requirejs block will print "hello" first. Second will be "hello" `inside` requirejs block, "hello" from `it` block doesnt print.

Comment: Have you tried `jasmine-node --coffee --verbose ./`? Also, what is your spec file named? I think it has to have "spec" as part of the name, as in `Foo.spec.coffee`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems that jasmine-node and require.js are completely incompatible. That said, it is possible to run jasmine tests on require.js modules in node using a bit of extra code. Take a look at https://github.com/geddski/amd-testing to see how.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Tran is right, it's the spec in the file name for me.

I have this:

```
"scripts": {
   "install": "cake install",
   "test": "node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node --verbose --coffee --runWithRequireJs --captureExceptions spec"
},
```

in my package.json and I installed jasmine-node from inside the project `npm install jasmine-node`

Minimal test file called `RingBuffer.spec.coffee`

```
require ["disrasher"], (mod) ->

  describe "A test", ->
    it "should fail", ->
      expect(1).toEqual 0
```

It doesn't actually work at the moment because I haven't got the project hooked up with require properly I don't think. I'll post back here when it does.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is running into this, much has changed since this question was asked.  The first thing to check is still that you're naming your files like `thing.spec.coffee`.

But if you're running the tests and still seeing the output "0 tests", you need to make a JavaScript file with your requirejs config.  This *must* be JavaScript, not CoffeeScript.

```js
// requirejs-setup.js
requirejs = require('requirejs');
requirejs.config({ baseUrl: __dirname + '/../' });
```

Then tell jasmine to use this setup file:

```sh
jasmine-node --coffee --requireJsSetup requirejs-setup.js ./
```

One nice thing about this is that you don't need to include the requirejs config in every spec file.

I've tested this on node v12.16, jasmine-node v3.0.0, and requirejs v2.3.6.